# Installing libpcap on linux mint

Tags: linux, pcap

I'm trying to compile an application (openVAS), but when i type "./configure", it says this :

configure: error: you need to install pcap library with development files

I tried to install libpcap-dev on command line, but it's already installed.
What should I do ?

Comment: try to install libpcap0.8-dev

Comment: Have you tried adding OBS repository and install from binaries?
Actually I think you have openvas in mint repos, don't you?

Comment: Indeed, openvas server and client are in the repositories, but I couldn't manage to get them work.

Comment: But for this particular case it's much harder to compile from sources, believe me. Can you try again from mint repos and update your post so it contains both problems?

Comment: here's what I obtain when I try to install openvas-server : E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Did you tried ```apt-get -f install``` ? (As root ofc, or with sudo)

Comment: The same problem occurs.

Comment: Try to manually delete broken packages via ```sudo vim /var/lib/dpkg/status```

Comment: no idea how to do that

Comment: grep: /etc/openvas/openvasd.conf: No such file or directory
egrep: /etc/openvas/openvasd.conf: No such file or directory

What should I do ?

Comment: Can you add a paste with full error when you try to install this or go for a -f install? I think something is broken and need more details